# backup mysql column is value with php post

Tags: php, mysql

I trying create a simple profile edit page. **Don't care syntax, I've refined**

```
<?php

$resultMember = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE email='".$_SESSION['memberEmail']."'");
..
$oldProfilePhoto = $resultMember['pp'];
..
{ //post controll
    $W = " WHERE email='".$_SESSION['memberEmail']."' AND pasw='".$_SESSION['memberPsw']."'";
    if(!isset($_FILES['profilePhoto']['value'])){
        mysql_query("UPDATE member SET pp='".$oldProfilePhoto."'".$W) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    $profilePhoto = "inc/img/".$_SESSION['memberSkype']."/".$_FILES['profilePhoto']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profilePhoto']['tmp_name'],$profilePhoto);
    mysql_query("UPDATE uye SET pp='".$profilePhoto."'".$W) or die(mysql_error());
}
..

?>
```

So, Image upload (**OK**), oldPhotoName get (**OK**), user select photo sent by post (**OK**), in short everthing (**OK**) but first changed profile photo after try change profile photos is return to empty. Not added oldphoto,

If the user chooses photos, old photo is not changed.

Thank you for your interest.
Good works..

Comment: Side note: Don't put to much trust in the session array, this is very dangerous when you are on an shared webhosting server. And you should make use off PDO / mysqli functions. The mysql functions will be removed from PHP in the future.

Comment: I remember say **Don't care syntax, I've refined**..

Comment: and, I am PDO learning..